# How to setup Yeoman and VS Code Extension under Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, yeoman-generator

I am using a Lubuntu 18.04 machine with Visual Studio Code

Version: 1.38.1

```
Commit: b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0
Date: 2019-09-11T13:30:08.229Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-64-generic
```

I am following the Visual Studio web page fundamental concepts for building extensions.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

I have Node.js and Git installed, but when I try to install Yeoman and VS Code Extension Generator with the following command I get an error.

```
$ npm install generator-code
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-64-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "generator-code"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/tux/npm-debug.log
```

Is this procedure supposed to run under (L)Ubuntu 18.04 or do I need any special Linux distribution or a different O.S. ?

---

**[SOLUTION BELOW]**

```
$ sudo npm install -g yo generator-code

npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
...
Everything looks all right!
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for chalk@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: chalk@4.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for yeoman-generator@4.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: yeoman-generator@4.10.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for semver@7.3.2: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: semver@7.3.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for execa@4.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: execa@4.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-api@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-api@1.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for human-signals@1.1.1: wanted: {"node":">=8.12.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: human-signals@1.1.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for global-agent@2.1.8: wanted: {"node":">=10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: global-agent@2.1.8
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for semver@7.3.2: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: semver@7.3.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for twig@1.15.1: wanted: {"node":">=8.16"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: twig@1.15.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for execa@4.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: execa@4.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-api@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-api@1.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for semver@7.3.2: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: semver@7.3.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for yeoman-generator@4.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: yeoman-generator@4.10.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for human-signals@1.1.1: wanted: {"node":">=8.12.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: human-signals@1.1.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for semver@7.3.2: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: semver@7.3.2

+ yo@3.1.1
+ generator-code@1.2.13
added 1153 packages from 400 contributors in 45.52s
```

**IMPORTANT : restore permissions**

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/tux/.config
```

Then call yo

```
$ yo code
? ==========================================================================
We're constantly looking for ways to make yo better! 
May we anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time? 
More info: https://github.com/yeoman/insight & http://yeoman.io
========================================================================== No

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │   Welcome to the Visual  │
    |--(o)--|    │   Studio Code Extension  │
   `---------´   │        generator!        │
    ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯
    /___A___\   /
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

? What type of extension do you want to create? (Use arrow keys)
❯ New Extension (TypeScript) 
  New Extension (JavaScript) 
  New Color Theme 
  New Language Support 
  New Code Snippets 
  New Keymap 
  New Extension Pack
```

Answer questions

```
# ? What type of extension do you want to create? New Extension (TypeScript)
# ? What's the name of your extension? HelloWorld
### Press <Enter> to choose default for all options below ###

# ? What's the identifier of your extension? helloworld
# ? What's the description of your extension? LEAVE BLANK
# ? Initialize a git repository? Yes
# ? Which package manager to use? npm

code ./helloworld
```

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

And at the end

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                yo update check failed                 │
│          Try running with sudo or get access          │
│         to the local update config store via          │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/tux/.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Try to run through sudo `sudo npm install -g yo generator-code`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've hit a [`npm` bug](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/348) triggered by packages that use the new [type="module" package.json parameter](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field).

Try updating your version of `npm`:

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```